# Custom wordpress template (own created) in conflict with UltimateMember

Tags: wordpress, templates, plugins

(Note! It's not necessary to know what is UltimateMember to can help me)

I created a custom template for a customer and I have a little problem with the plugin UltimateMember, plugin that allow users have a custom profile (upload avatar photo and little more). The problem is, when I try to change avatar photo, the modal windows that allow you choose a photo, does not appear using my template. It works great with default wordpress templates.

Here two interesting pics about this situation. You can see that "This" is not charged in my custom template and I don't understand why...

Default template: 
http://tattoobiter.com/default.png

Custom template:
http://tattoobiter.com/custom.png

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, It seems wordpress have problems to charge javascript external scripts if don't have